# Can't install Django 1.11 version with python 2.7 virtual environment

Tags: django, ubuntu, installation

I am trying to setup Django-2.0 & Django-1.11 version in my system with virtual environment.I done the Django-2.0 version with python-3 and am able to run the server.

But I am facing an issue when am able to install django-1.11 with python-2.7 it's installing Django-2.0 instead of Django-1.11

```
>>> import django
>>> print(django.get_version())
```

it's giving **1.11**

```
django-admin startproject projectname
```

When I run this command it's installing Django-2.0 and my **django_admin --version** is 2.0

Comment: That's because your `django-admin` script is from the 2.0 install and not from the 1.11 installation. Make sure you have activated the correct virtual environment before you run the command.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid...i activated that virtual class, Is there any chance if that latest version django-admin not setup with virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `python -m django` instead of `django-admin`. This will ensure that it is using the django install for the active virtual environment.

```
python -m django startproject myproject
```